# Detecting if a shell redirect command runs out of diskspace?

Tags: linux, sh

I need to do a

```
sort big-file | uniq > big-file.temp
```

called from a C program via system. 
Does this report an error when the file system gets full?

A man 2 "write" only returns 0 if it can't write all the data, but /dev/null always returns 0 and the bash is not reporting an error when piping into it, so i guess i will not receive an error notification.

Comment: Aside: The shell interpreting strings passed to `system()` is not bash, it's `/bin/sh`. As such, this question should be tagged `sh`, not `bash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the disk fills up, `uniq` will get an error when it's writing to stdout, and it should then exit with a non-zero exit code. The return value of [`system()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) is the termination status of the last command in the pipeline. So if the command is successful, `system()` will return `0`, if the command is not successful it will return some non-zero value.

So you can do:

```
ret = system('sort big-file | uniq > big-file.temp');
if (ret != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Sorting failed!\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

BTW, [`sort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) has a `-u` option to generate unique results, this is probably more efficient than sorting everything and then piping to `uniq`.

Comment: unfortunately -u in sort only checks the same key but i need to remove only if the non key is also same. So i have to use sort and uniq as pipe

Comment: Since your example didn't use the `-k` option to sort, I assumed the key was the whole record.